# How to start running with MSVC

Tags: c, debugging, visual-c++, compilation, visual-studio-debugging

Starting from the beginning !!
can anybody here help me how to start running C project with MSVC ?

I have all the source files under:

```
src/ directory
```

all the header files under:

```
inc/ directory
```

and few of the source under:

```
test/ directory
```

test directory contains **makefile** for the project

How can I use the same setup in MSVC for compilation and debugging ?

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head,

1. [Create a workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138514(v=vs.100).aspx). Determine whether your application is a command-line, GUI, DLL, etc.
2. [Create a project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7(v=vs.100).aspx) (or projects depending on how your application is structured).
3. [Add each file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx) to the appropriate project.
4. Set compiler options if any.
5. Compile and fix any portability issues (such as compiler directives).

Regarding your makefile, check out [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1227714/1383051) which talks about [cccl](http://cccl.sourceforge.net/).

> cccl is a wrapper around Microsoft Visual C++'s cl.exe and link.exe. It converts Unix compiler parameters into parameters understood by cl and link.